# SOAP Client Request --> Bad Request

Tags: soap, soap-client, bad-request

I've been asked to look into syncing data using a SOAP service. I don't really know SOAP very well at all and I get a Bad Request Error.

The function I'm trying to call is a test echo function:

**public string EchoAuthenticated(string text)**

Each time I call it I get an error.

I have commented out the username / password setting as I don't know the username and password right now and my contact person is on leave :( Right now though I'd be perfectly happy just to get an authentication failed message rather than an error...

If anyone could point me in the right direction here please...

Thanks,

John

```
 <?php

 $apiUrl         = 'https://exdev.api.propctrl.co.za/v3/Integration.svc?wsdl';
 $options        = array( 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1,  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2);

 try
 {
    $client     = new SoapClient($apiUrl, $options);

    //$data       = array(
    //  'Username'          => "test",
    //  'Password'          => "test"
    //);

    //$header = new SoapHeader('https://exdev.api.propctrl.co.za/v3/', 'CredentialsHeader', $data, false);
    //$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());


    print $client->EchoAuthenticated("Test String");
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:

```
...
$client     = new SoapClient($apiUrl, $options);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$auth = array("Username" => "John", "Password" => "secret", 
    "IsP24Credentials" => false);
$header = new SoapHeader("https://www.propctrl.com/", "CredentialsHeader", 
    $auth, FALSE);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

print $client->EchoAuthenticated(array( 
    "text" => "My text to be echoed."
));
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
...
```

This should result in a request SOAP request like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="https://www.propctrl.com/v3" xmlns:ns2="https://www.propctrl.com/">
   <env:Header>
      <ns2:CredentialsHeader>
         <ns2:IsP24Credentials>false</ns2:IsP24Credentials>
         <ns2:Password>secret</ns2:Password>
         <ns2:Username>John</ns2:Username>
      </ns2:CredentialsHeader>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:EchoAuthenticated>
         <ns1:text>My text to be echoed.</ns1:text>
      </ns1:EchoAuthenticated>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

As a side note, you might have a look at http://www.soapui.org/. This tool helps greatly with web service development.

Comment: Hey Marcellus, thanks for the reply. I didn't get that to work, however I am going to download soapui and see what's being sent...